# Is there a comprehensive list of Google App Engine applications out there?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm considering leveraging Google App Engine for a small side project, but before I go in head first and start coding my apps (which are fairly trivial and common stuff) I'd like to check out what has already been done. But I haven't been able to find any place that lists the sorts of applications already out there. Anyone knows of such a place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There would be the [App Gallery](http://appgallery.appspot.com/) for a starter...

Answer (score 2):

Probably not comprehensive, but pretty close: [Google App Engine Applications Gallery](http://appgallery.appspot.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Also not comprehensive, but here are [some that use app-engine-patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/wiki/ProjectsUsingAppEnginePatch)

Answer (score 2):

The App Engine gallery has unfortunately been closed.

Google has a page on the Developers portal where they feature products and apps built with their technologies and API. The features items are handpicked by the Google Developers team (which you can always try to contact on G+).

You can filter that list based on which technology was used so the following link (with an appengine filter) will show you the apps built on App Engine:

https://developers.google.com/showcase/#tags=appengine